# Learning chord inversions

Tags: piano, chords, technique

I am getting the R & L hand patterns for triads but has anyone got an idea for practicing inversions of all the 7th chords? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You just play them! There are 4 notes in each, so the compass of one hand for each of the four notes is logical. Whatever fingering you decide, as your hand is peculiar to you.

Bear in mind all the 7th chords - maj.7, min.7, dom.7, aug.7, dim 7, min. maj 7, min7b5, should cover it.

And when you can play them in unison, have a go at playing, say, 1st inv. l.h. along with 2nd inv. r.h. That's enough to keep practising for a long, long time!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tim's suggestion, I would also suggest splitting them up between the two hands, two notes in each hand, in both open and closed positions.  This is partly for the benefit of ear training, as well as helping the fingers learn the intervals.